# Devise: remove module for extended model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, devise

I got big legacy app with model `User`. I added new type of user:

```rb
class ExtendedUser < User
  devise :database_authenticatable, ...
end
```

New type of user is extending existing one, so all code written for `User` should work also for `ExtendedUser`, without extending it is impossible.

Question is how to remove devise module from `ExtendedUser` which comes from `User`?

`User` is confirmable and `ExtendedUser` should not be.

I'm suspecting that removing module is impossible and easiest way is to put `.skip_confirmation!` before all places in code where this user will be created and where email can change.

Comment: I really don't think this is possible. This is syntactic sugar on top of `Module#include` and Ruby does not have an "uninclude" mechanism to remove a module once it has been included.

Comment: You can just override the `confirmed?` method in the subclass (return true) and it will act like its confirmed.

Comment: @max checked, confirmation instructions still sending, `.update(email: 'new@ema.il')` still updates column `unconfirmed_email` and sends email, so this trick not negating all effects

Answer (score 1):

You could just use inheritance to dynamically evaluate which modules are included:

```
class User < User
  devise *devise_modules
  # ...
  def self.devise_modules
    [:database_authenticatable, ...]
  end
end

class ExtendedUser < User
  # ...
  def self.devise_modules
    super.excluding(:confirmable)
  end
end
```